# Why is my section not going below a header in HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css

Hello I am new to HTML and CSS.

I have a quick question about my code.

**Objective:**

I am aiming to achieve the following layout for my page.

```
Navigation bar,

Title (h1),

Title (h2),

Button,

Section (About me)
```

**Code:**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


html,
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Lato', 'Arial', 'sans-serif';
  font-weight: 300;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}


.row {
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

section {
  padding: 80px 0;
}


.title-text-box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: white;
}

.title-text-box h1, .title-text-box h2{
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgba(50,25,55,0.5);
}


.header-img {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right,#ff7e5f, #feb47b);
  padding: 40px;
}


.title-text-box h1 {
  font-size: 280%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.main-nav {
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.main-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.main-nav li:last-child {
  margin-right: 20px;
}


.main-nav li a:link,
.main-nav li a:visited {
  padding: 7px 0;
  color: #5b86e5;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 100%;
}

.main-nav li a:after {
  display:block;
  content: '';
  border-bottom: solid 3px #ff5e62;
  border-radius: 25px;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
}

.main-nav li a:hover:after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}


.btn:link,
.btn:visited {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  margin-top: 90px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #ff5e62;
  transition: all .2s;
}

.btn:hover {
  transform: translateY(-3px);
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.btn:active {
  transform: translateY(-1px);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
  <body>

  <header>
    <nav>
      <div class="row">
      <ul class="main-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="title-text-box header-img">
      <h1>Header1</h1>
      <h2>Header2.</h2>
      <a class="btn" href="#">Discover</a>
    </div>
  </header>

<section class="section-about-me">
  <div class="row">
    <h3>About me</h2>
  </div>

</section>

  </body>
</html>
```

**Question regarding my current code:**

I am really confused why the `about me` section is below the `nav-bar` and above the `header`? Whereas on the `html` it is below the header?

Also the code snippet only works on full screen. How can I fit it on the sample screen below?

Thanks

Comment: If you set the header container with absolute position this is suppose to happen. So it will change the "flow" of other elements in the container (body). I think the question is to complex to be answered in the current state. Please take a look in basic CSS styling and or CSS flex and how to do that. This would be a good starting point if you want to design a layout from scratch. There are also a lot of useful existing templates on GitHub you can learn from e.g. startbootstrap or what you would like to use. This is just a pointer if you want to do stuff like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the 3 changes required to make the header, nav and about-me section work as per the expectation:

1. In the HTML file, move the header into a separate row after nav.
2. In CSS, set the nav element to align right and take up full width of the page.
3. In CSS, sert the Header element to occupy full width of page and also have a top margin, so that it would not overlap with nav.

**Here is the working example:**

**index.html file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
  <body>

  <header>
    <nav>
      <div class="row">
          <ul class="main-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="title-text-box header-img">
      <h1>Header1</h1>
      <h2>Header2.</h2>
      <a class="btn" href="#">Discover</a>
    </div>
  </div>

<section class="section-about-me">
  <div class="row">
    <h3>About me</h2>
  </div>

</section>

  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS file (style/style.css):**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


html,
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Lato', 'Arial', 'sans-serif';
  font-weight: 300;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}


.row {
  width: 100%;
}

section {
  padding: 80px 0;
}


.title-text-box {
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: white;
}

.title-text-box h1, .title-text-box h2{
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgba(50,25,55,0.5);
}


.header-img {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right,#ff7e5f, #feb47b);
  padding: 40px;
}


.title-text-box h1 {
  font-size: 280%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.main-nav {
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 60px;

  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.main-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.main-nav li:last-child {
  margin-right: 20px;
}


.main-nav li a:link,
.main-nav li a:visited {
  padding: 7px 0;
  color: #5b86e5;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 100%;
}

.main-nav li a:after {
  display:block;
  content: '';
  border-bottom: solid 3px #ff5e62;
  border-radius: 25px;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
}

.main-nav li a:hover:after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}


.btn:link,
.btn:visited {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  margin-top: 90px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #ff5e62;
  transition: all .2s;
}

.btn:hover {
  transform: translateY(-3px);
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.btn:active {
  transform: translateY(-1px);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

Comment: That is legendary! You've saved me hours of research aha!

Answer (score 0):

The about me section is below the nav-bar and the header because you used absolute positioning on your header:

```
.title-text-box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: white;
}
```

Hence the `.title-text-box` will be 40% top and 50% left. No matter where other (relative) elements in this container are located.

On your second question, I would suggest to dig deeper in responsive layout design. There are a lot of useful templates and frameworks you can learn from.

I would suggest [HTML layouting](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_layout.asp) and [flex layouting](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) with CSS or any of the existing CSS libraries e.g. [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/).

Great existing templates to learn templating and layouting from are in my opinion [startbootstrap](https://startbootstrap.com/). But this is just a personal preference.